# INI File With Duplicate Keys

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, vb6

Say I have an INI file like so:

```
[123]
name=Ryan
name=Joe
```

How would I retrieve "name=Ryan\nname=Joe" using API calls such as [GetPrivateProfileSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724348%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, GetPrivateProfileSection will return it.  GetPrivateProfileString() can obviously only ever retrieve "Ryan".  You won't get the string handed to you like you want, the name/value pairs are separated by a zero.  The end of the list is indicated by two zeros.  You'll need to account for that when you parse it.

Comment: GetPrivateProfileSection doesn't seem to return it. It only returns "name=Ryan"

Comment: I tested this before I posted, I'm quite sure it works.  Perhaps you missed the comment about the zeros?  The 2nd string is at &buf[strlen(buf)+1].